# Lighting issues in render + artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

So, I´m trying to render the camera scene in the first image, but when i render it it bugs out and gets those weird black triangles, besides becoming pitch black. For reference, another scene rendered in the same space.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Patterned triangle artifacts like that are usually the result of an OpenGL error (or rarely, a failing GPU) - make sure your graphics drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be [Z fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Check if there are no duplicate meshes, or faces. If You have a plane, for example, select its border edges and press f, it will make a face that effectively duplicates the mesh and is very hard to notice.

Comment: This solved it, thank u for the help.